Microcontroller source impedance concern a
I am trying to read in a very fast signal using an Arduino MCU. Since the Arduino has a slow ADC onboard (around 9600 samples per second), I have decided to use a capacitor to store the voltage so that the slow ADC has enough time to read the signal. The 4.72nF capacitor will slowly discharge using the 100Meg resistor. My issue is that the MCU recommends a source impedance of 10k or less to allow the 14pF internal sampling capacitor to charge/discharge to fast enough to the required level. I am not sure if the 100Meg resistor will be an issue since I am giving the ADC enough time to read the signal. (I am reading the voltage across the 4.7nF capacitor)


Spend a lot more effort describing your fast signal source and your application requirements.

The fast signal is not a concern as I am able to successfully capture it. The capacitor has the value I want stored so I am only concerned about the source impedance. So the capacitor has a DC value that it holds for a period long enough for the slow ADC to read.

Personally, I'm unable to begin to think about this without knowing details you haven't shared. And that circuit looks many ways too wrong. I'll take your point to mean you are saying that I'm out of my depth and that I should leave this to others with better crystal balls. Granted.

What is C1 doing here? A floating DC level at the ADC input will produce random conversion values over time and temperature. R21 cannot discharge the 4.7 nF (10n?) capacitor.

What MCU is in your Arduino? There are many different models.

Doesn't the common ADCs found in MCU already store the sampled value in a capacitor? Read its data sheet and look for "sample and hold".

Please [edit] your question to clarify and add new information, this is not a forum.
